# Jade Iteration: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I have a issue with the jade iteration. I want iterate sequelize query results on my jade page. This is my code :

route.js

```
app.get('/cpanel/access-control', function(req, res) {
        if (req.session.user == null) {
            res.redirect('/cpanel/login');
        }   else {
            res.render('cpanel/access-control', {
                udata : req.session.user
            });
        }
        CB.getAllRecords( function(e, chatbot) {
            res.render('cpanel/access-control', { chatbot : chatbot });
        })
    });
```

access.jade

```
ul.menu-sidebar
 each chatbot in chatbot
  li
   a(href='#')
    span.fa.fa-circle-o
    #{chatbot.botname}
```

command prompt

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `chatbot` is empty or not defined?? Make sure that in your `routes.js` chatbot have value..

Comment: when I console.log (chatbot) on route.js appears in the console

Comment: Can you please post the chatbot value??

Comment: [ { _id: 5a2f8edf84b906480af0d121,
    botname: 'Chat Bot',
    description: 'Chat Bot',
    status: 'inactive' } ]

Comment: i try to understand jade code, i think jade code  each chatbot in chatbot  is like javascript code for(chatbot of chatbot), so, first chatbot is an array, but second chatbot is an object.

Comment: so, do you have solution for my code? how to write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ul.menu-sidebar
 each chat in chatbot
  li
   a(href='#')
    span.fa.fa-circle-o
    #{chat.botname}
```

You can't have the looping variable name and the array name same. 
Also do

```
   console.log(chatbot)
```

Just to verify you get the JSON in the terminal.